# Hows App server and GCM server are different in functioning?

Tags: android

I follow this link   [PLease see here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-device-to-device-messaging-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-via-http/)    . Can anyone tell me  exact process to communication between two  mobile devices in terms of push notification. Please help me.

Comment: You can find lot of examples of implementing GCM

Comment: Hi @Clairvoyant ,Yes I know there is lots of example but i expect some more clarification and some good link . I do not understand my down-casting  :(

Answer (score 0):

GCM is a google cloud messaging http server.It is used for providing notification service on android phones any notification you receive on your phone is sent through GCM.Every device using a specific application is registered with GCM. Even if you want your application to send notification to the user on occurrence of something it's not possible without GCM.